# Transfer an Injustice profile between platforms?

Tags: injustice-gods-among-us

I currently play Injustice on the Xbox 360. I will soon be getting a PS4 and would like to retain my name and experience. Is there any way to do this?

Does the WBID allow for this, or is there no way to transfer a profile between platforms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is absolutely no way to do this.